# Spring Batch - Error with JobBuilderFactory Bean Not Found"

Tags: java

```
package com.example.board.job;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.example.board.dto.BoardDto;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<BoardDto> reader() {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<BoardDto>()
            .name("myEntityReader")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .sql("SELECT * FROM board")
            .rowMapper(new BoardRowMapper())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<BoardDto> writer() {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<BoardDto>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO board VALUES (:id, :title, :content, :writer)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<BoardDto, BoardDto>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job myJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            .start(step1())
            .build();
    }


}
```

I want to use spring boot batch 5 to create a batch program that reads data from a bulletin board database and saves it to another table. How can I make it?The code above is the code that produces an error. I don't know why the error 'JobBuilderFactory ' that could not be found keeps popping up.

Comment: I have a similar issue in my IDE. For some reason, Job- and StepBuilders have an "no bean found" issue, but the code works perfectly. When do you get this error? compile time? runtime? or is it just a "flag" in your IDE?

Answer (score 1):

`JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory` are deprecated for Spring Batch v5. You have to use `JobBuilder` and `StepBuilder` instead.

[Here is the official documentation with an example about this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#jobbuilderfactory-and-stepbuilderfactory-bean-exposureconfiguration)

[And this is the reason why this happened in v5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4188)